# React Native Watchman error In window 10

Tags: npm, react-native, watchman

From here i download as per given steps 
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html
After Installation of watchmen i get this issue.
'watchman' is not recognized as an internal or external command.enter image description hereI follow all the steps given in below link.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL3Qp.png)

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: Please mention Watchman version.First Check watchman has installed by:
watchman -v
result like : 4.9.4